# Non-public selectors when submitting iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, non-public-selectors

How can I debug this?

The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp: log:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:format:args:

I have uploaded 6 versions before without incident. Without changes, why would app validator complain about this? How do I find the code that causes this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use 3rd party lib? Probably from DDLog?

Comment: Yes it was a 3rd party. But does DDLog use a non-public selector?